# Lost game progress after converting offline account to xbox live

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

First of all, I am completely new to Xbox community. I purchased it in a last week and still has small knowledge about it, so please be understanding.

I've been playing with my brother on my Xbox 360 E console for a couple of days. We were playing spit-screen on our offline accounts. Then, today, I decided to click "Join Xbox Live" for some reasons. Everything went smooth and now I have an online account. My brother did nothing with his account.

After that we wanted to continue our campaign in Aliens: Colonial Marines. We logged (myself with a new Xbox live account, and my brother with his old offline account) in, and realized that there is no option "continue campaign"! We can only start a new campaign from scratch. Moreover, my brother of course has all of his equipment and I lost mine. But, what is worth mentioning, all my Xbox achievements survived. So, my new online account, has some remains from my old offline account, but the most important part: saved games seem to be missing in action.

Has anybody encountered such problem? Is it possible that all my saved games are lost? Where does Xbox keep them? Is there anything I can do to try to bring them back? I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Have you checked to see if your saves exist on your HD still? If you're on the dashboard, go to your settings and there should be a Storage option. (Something along those lines at least, I'm not at home so this is from memory)

Comment: Not that I've personally done this, however it could be that your ID has changed (Local ID may have turned into the XBL ID) and thus it isn't tied to your account. It is easy to change this but crosses into the scope beyond what this site is used for.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that the game defaults to using Cloud Save. When you didn't have Xbox Live you also didn't have the option for cloud saves. When you upgraded you got access to them and the game might be trying to read them instead of your hard drive.

If this is what's wrong there are two fixes:

1. Change the settings in the game to use the hard drive instead of cloud saves
2. Move the save file from the hard drive to the cloud saves in your system settings